# What is running time of Voronoi diagram for Manhattan distance l1 norm?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Cannot find the algorithm for Voronoi on Manhattan distance and its running time. Can someone point to the relevant resources?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This question has been long over due, but if the OP still wants a reference, then they should consider the following:

- For general $\ell_p$ norms consider:

*Chew, L. Paul; Kedem, Klara; Sharir, Micha; Tagansky, Boaz; Welzl, Emo*, Voronoi diagrams of lines in 3-space under polyhedral convex distance functions, Clarkson, K. (ed.), Proceedings of the 6th annual ACM-SIAM symposium on discrete algorithms, San Francisco, CA, USA, January 22-24, 1995. Philadelphia, PA: SIAM. 197-204 (1995). [ZBL0848.68107](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0848.68107).

- For $\ell_1$ norm (Manhattan distance) in particular:

*Hwang, F. K.*, [**An O(n log n) algorithm for rectilinear minimal spanning trees**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/322123.322124), J. Assoc. Comput. Mach. 26, 177-182 (1979). [ZBL0395.68064](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0395.68064).

*Lee, D. T.; Wong, C. K.*, [**Voronoi diagrams in $L_1(L_\infty)$ metrics with 2-dimensional storage applications**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0209017), SIAM J. Comput. 9, 200-211 (1980). [ZBL0447.68111](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0447.68111).